# Is a Firebase instance id confidential Data?

Tags: firebase

I have a Question about the Firebase instance id and how private i have to keep it. Is it a good idea to have it in a publicly acessable ( for all logged-in Users) Profile Document in Firestore or would it be better to store it in the users private one? ( Of course i dont want to display the Instance-id, only my Database-Structure would be a little bit nicer)

I hope somebody know what a person who gets it through reverse-engineering can do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Firebase documentation still refers to the Instance ID as the *registration token*. The [Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) says this about the registration token:

> Registration token: A unique token string that identifies each client app instance. The registration token is required for single device and device group messaging. **Note that registration tokens must be kept secret.**

There is no further explanation of why it must be kept a secret though. This previous question about the same topic, gives some explanation: [Why must I keep the registration token secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102017/why-must-i-keep-the-registration-token-secret) What this says is indeed true: someone who has access to both your FCM server key, and the instance ID can send messages on your behalf.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, the instance id is useless unless someone has my Fcm Server Key?